# Streaming VLC video to Android through HTTP using VideoView

Tags: java, android, networking

I have been trying to stream video from VLC to Android using VideoView. The following is the VLC command I have been using, which I know works because I have tested it in a web browser:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{width=150,vcodec=VP80,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=200}:std{access=http{mime=video/webm},mux=ffmpeg{mux=webm},dst=localhost:6124/media.webm}' --sout-keep
```

The code I am using for the videoview is as follows:

```
String url = "http://" + destinationIP + ":" + 6124 + "/media.webm";

vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
vidView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
vidView.requestFocus();
vidView.start();
```

This is the only error message I see in LogCat:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

And the message I get on android is a dialog saying "Can't play this video."

I found all of these error messages very useless, and it looks like nobody is having quite the same problem I am having. What is going wrong?